# is it Visual Studio 2010 IDE bug?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

1. making a templete for window with ContentPresenter.
2. applying template.
3. place a control in the window.

The placed control's region(adorner decorator) is not correct. (biased to top left). The control displayed right position.

When this project is loaded in Expression Blend, this window was displayed properly. (adorner is too)

Is this a Visual Studio 2010 IDE bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem with Visual Studio.  When you apply a template to a Window, some objects that are then added to the window do not display in the correct position at design time.  This does not seem to affect proper run-time behavior/display.

An example:  A Grid control (the design outline) will be displayed with the origin shifted to the upper-left corner, but the contents of the Grid will be displayed properly.